# Al utilizar una variable desde otro archivo aparece el error "Undefined variable $"

Tags: php7

Estoy utilizando una variable desde otro archivo y me aparece un error "undefined variable $crud".
Este es el contenido:
Archivo que general el error, **index.php**:

```
$crud->dataview("SELECT * FROM tbl_users");
```

Esta es la función **dataview** que esta en el archivo **class.crud.php**:

```
public function dataview($query) 
{

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute();   
    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) 
    {   
        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  
        {                                           
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php print($row['id']); ?></td> 
                <td><?php print($row['first_name']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['last_name']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['email_id']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['contact_no']); ?></td>
                <td align="center">
                
                <a href="edit-data.php?edit_id=<?php print($row['id']); ?>">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> 
                </a>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                
                <a href="delete.php?delete_id=<?php print($row['id']); ?>">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i>
                </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td>Acune utilisateur...</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Archivo **index.php**

```
include_once 'dbconfig.php'; 
include_once 'crud.php';
include_once 'header.php';

<div class="container">

<a href="add-data.php" class="btn btn-large btn-info">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> &nbsp; Add users
</a>
</div>
<br />
<div class="container"> 

<table class='table table-bordered table-responsive'> 
    <tr>
        <th>N°</th>
        <th>Nombre </th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
        <th>E - mail</th>
        <th>Teléfono</th>
        <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <?php

    /** @var object $crud */
    $crud->dataview("SELECT * FROM tbl_users");
    ?>
</table> 
</div>
```

Cómo debo declarar la variable $crud para que no me muestre este error?

Comment: Si `dataview` no está dentro de una clase puedes hacer `dataview(..)` sin mas..

Si está dentro de una clase: `$crud = ClassName()` ... `$crud->dataview(...)`

Comment: **nax** ciertamente _dataview_ esta dentro de la clase **crud** en el archivo **class.crud.php**. No entendí la parte donde explicas como puedo usarlo en este caso.

Comment: Otra cosa, $crud es una instancia de la class crud(la cual tiene un parámetro que almacena la conexión PDO con MySQL).
    `$crud = new crud(DB_con);`

Comment: Adicionando un comentário: 
`/** @var object $crud */`
Conseguí que no apareciese más ese error en el PHPStorm.

Comment: Estás usando un class loader? si es así tienes que importar el namespace. Si no usas class loaders tienes que hacer un include del fichero donde está la clase. Entiendo que ese `$crud = new` lo estás haciendo en el fichero class.crud.php

Comment: el `$crud = new`lo estoy usando desde otro archivo (index.php) que es de donde llamo a los métodos de la `class crud` que se encuentra en el fichero class.crud.php.
Hize un `include_once 'class,crud.php'  ` en el fichero index.php y no resolvió eso. No estoy usando en un class loader desde index.php

Comment: deberías actualizar la pregunta con el index.php al completo. Y con la clase al completo.. así podemos realmente hacernos una idea de que pasa

Comment: Sí perfecto. Voy adicionarlo @nax.

Comment: Sigo sin ver donde creas la variable $crud

Comment: La varible `$crud` es una instancia de la class **crud** y esta instanciada en el archivo `dbconfig.php`